# how do i filter columns with data_type= object

Tags: pandas, dataframe, label-encoding

```
encoder=LabelEncoder()
categorical_features=df.columns.tolist()
for col in categorical_features:
    df[col]=encoder.fit_transform(df[col])
df.head(20)
```

**i want categorical_features to take columns with datatype=object

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for col in categorical_features:
    if df.dtypes[col] == "object":
        print('object type')
    else:
        print(f'something else {df.dtypes[col]}')
```

you can modify your code like

```
categorical_features=df.columns.tolist()
for col in categorical_features:
    if df.dtypes[col] == "object"
       df[col]=encoder.fit_transform(df[col])
```

Comment: how do i write this in single line with column name separated by commas 
encoder=LabelEncoder()
x['day']=encoder.fit_transform(x['day'] )
x['sex']=encoder.fit_transform(x['sex'] )
x['smoker']=encoder.fit_transform(x['smoker'])
x['time']=encoder.fit_transform(x['time'])

Comment: what is x here ?

Comment: x is df dataframe

Comment: cols = ['day','sex','smoker','time'] 
for c in cols:
  x[c] = encoder.fit_transform(x[c])

Answer (score 0):

to select all object type columns in pandas you can use:

```
categorical_features = df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
```

The `select_dtypes()` was released in Pandas `v 0.14.1`